# How is Timatic pronounced?

Tags: terminology, timatic

Travellers are often advised to refer to Timatic for visa information (or to ask airline staff to check). However, what is the correct pronunciation of Timatic? Is it approx *Tim-a-tick*, or *Tie-matic* (to rhyme with automatic)? Or is it something else?

Comment: Presumably, people pronounce it differently depending on their accents, just like *directed* or *divergent.*

Comment: "- matic" is an American marketingism.  It's just "tih - matic", like automatic or 1000 other "-matic" brand names.

Answer (score 8):

Referring to [IATAtv YouTube](https://youtu.be/5hAqOTCGG3k) the first syllable is pronounced as a 'tem' not 'time'. Hence the word would sound like:

> Tem a tik

You can listen to it at [forvo](https://forvo.com/word/timatic/) as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can hear the presumably IATA preferred pronunciation in this video:

[Timatic Sourcing](http://www.iata.org/publications/timatic/Pages/timatic-sourcing.aspx)

te-matic as opposed to tea-matic or tie-matic.  Like Timothy, or Timone from the Lion King.

[Direct YouTube link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=eroJZdDQXP0)

Comment: So which one is it?

Comment: For those who can't watch the video (it's hosted on Youtube), it's close to _Tie-matic_, but with a short vowel in _Tie_, sometimes closer to _Ta_ than _Ti_.

A direct link to the video is [ https://youtu.be/eroJZdDQXP0 ]

Comment: @jpatokal What do you mean?  It's pronounced consistently in the video.  At least, I didn't notice a difference.

Comment: @Johns-305 Videos come and videos go, but Travel.SE is forever, so please put the answer in the answer ;)

Comment: Interestingly, for some speakers of English _pen_ and _pin_ sound similar but not for all. I could not imagine _tim(atic)_ being pronounced _tem(atic)_ and @CSM indicates it is rather like _tim_ (insstead of _time_).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like *Tim-a-tick* to me, and this is also how I pronounce it. Never caused any difficulties.